# Is there way to store values in GLSL vertex shader and editing them from there

Tags: opengl, glsl

I need to store value for other vertices. For example in pseudo

```
static float position_x = 0; // I know there is not static keyword in glsl but I need something like it
gl_Position = vec4(position_x++, 0, 0, 1);
```

so the problem is that how do we save the "position_x" for other vertices as well.

Comment: It's difficult to answer this question without having more of an idea of what this "value" you want to "store" represents. There are many possible answers, and which one is appropriate depends on the very specific nature of what you're trying to do.

Comment: In the example I would like to store the float value. Since when other vetrex loads the position would just go back to 0, but I want it to be the old value. So if theres a way to store it. I could just store it, read it and modify it.

Comment: That's just a restatement of what you asked. I'm asking for clarification on what this value *means*, what you intend to do with it. In the example code you give, you are effectively suggesting that each VS invocation would get a monotonically increasing value. Well, VS's *already have* one of those (or something close to it), so maybe that would serve your needs better than trying to store an arbitrary value and modify it from a bunch of different, concurrently executing VS invocations.

Comment: The original usage would be for constructing text (for rendering) in gpu and for each character I will need to move x offset for each instance of character. So I will need the old x position inorder to know where to place the new character for another instance.

Comment: Nico Bolas told you: "*concurrently executing VS invocations*" (Think of it as multithreaded). For "hello" text, one VS invocation may be rendering "o" while another invocation is still rendering "h". So, forget that idea of "old x position"

Comment: Okay thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Search in this site for "opengl text rendering" and you'll find very useful answers.